# Parse HTML files then edit them in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, replace, navbar

So my problem is that I want to have a website that has a single navbar.html file. That I can use to add to the other pages in my website. I figured the best way to do this without javascript which I am trying to avoid because of compatibility issues (school website so I am trying to get best compatibility). I am writing this website for my school so I don't know what is going to happen to it from now on but I want to create an automated system that can parse the folder for html files then go into each and find the `<nav id="mainNav">.....</nav>` and then replace all the content between those two tags with content from one central navbar.html so that someone can just go in change the navbar.html then run this script and it would just auto update the webpages.

Now I'm not asking anyone to write the code for me I have a basic to intermediate understanding of python so if anyone could point me in the right direction such as maybe what would be the possible ways to go about this. Thanks for the help.

Edit: I would like to only use standard libraries so that it is as easy as possible to move around preferably it would be just one *.py file

Edit: Please don't tell me to just go get a tool I can't do that the server does not have any server side programming languages best I can do is edit the local files then upload static pages to the server.

Edit: fixed it so that it was on topic. Hopefully.

Comment: Wouldn't XML be the right choice for these things? Maybe Python has a few utilities that can make your life a lot more easier.

Comment: You cannot serve a webpage easily without using a web framework. Are you trying to build only the HTML or also serve it as well as the responses?

Comment: What I'm trying to do I don't believe I would be able to do with xml correct me if I'm wrong I'm new to web development basically I am trying to take a chunk out of an html file and replace it with a chunk from another html file.

Comment: Ignore @JoeyEzekiel that's irrelevant; a templating engine does precisely what you want.

Comment: it's basically a static webpage all I want is a script someone can run in a offline folder that can edit the html files so they then can be re uploaded. The reason I am doing this because the tech guys at my school have been known to leave stuff out on the navbars when updating and I figured one file would be easier to edit then all of the webpages.

Comment: @ Eiyrioü von Kauyf - I don't quite follow here - who's talking about a templating engine. @ Chaos If I'm reading it correctly, all you need is to play with files and nothing to do with rendering HTML or anything of the sort. You just need one central file and when the script is run - put the content of the central file into individual html files for use. Is this what you need?

Comment: That is exactly what I need just moving one chunk of a file into another. I was hoping to scan the directory for html files then just find the nav tag and id then just replace the content inside of it

Comment: You want templating, yet you don't want to use a templating engine but instead do it "by hand". Prepare to end up with a hackish solution that's gonna be a pain to maintain.

Comment: I have just done some research on templating and from what I have looked at I have not found a single one that doesn't use some sort of server side scripting or javascript

Comment: Well I already accepted an answer and I only asked that if someone happened to know of a program that already allowed this then that would be nice. But I was very specific about what I wanted to do and how I was going to get there. So I don't understand the problem if there is a way I can just mark it as answered that would be nice still relatively new to this site.

Comment: I see no reason why this is considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. I just threw in the tool idea as an after thought. My main question was how would I go about parsing the html and replacing things withing specific tags. I can reword the question to leave out the tool suggestion part. Though I do understand that the comentors took this question off topic that is no reason to close my topic.

Comment: I fixed the question hopefully. This question has been keeping me from using stack exchange for 2 years know I really this can be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a lot of people criticizing what you are trying to do, and I'm going to join them.  This is a horrible way to implement a navbar, and a horrible procedural call for 'updating' a web site.  I would be very adamant with your school that this isn't a wise decision, and more time is going to be wasted in the end doing it in this archaic manner as opposed to also-free alternative like PHP or Python.

With that said, I will also help with your question, because it looks like (based on your commends and replies) implementing a templating engine or dynamic web content is beyond your control, and is thus not an option.  An approach could be to have the navbar replacement script (lets call it script.py) at the top of the HTML directory, and sitting beside the new navbar.html file.

First to get the files, find all files in the child directories using `os.walk`:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.join(os.getcwd(), "html_dir"):
    for file in files:
        # do something with the directories
    for dir in dirs:
        # do something with the directories
```

Obviously, you'll want to make this recursive, so that it applies to all HTML files in all subfolders.

Next, as far as the replacement goes, I'd recommend reading in the entirety of the navbar.html file with something simple like:

```
with open('file', 'r') as target_file:
    replacement_text = target_file.read()
```

To do the actual replacement, I'd recommend a Regular Expression.  Regular expressions will vary depending on content, and may need to be tweaked depending on the exact data being worked with.  They are also prone to breaking if this data changes.

```
import re 

new_html = re.sub(r'<nav id="mainNav">.*?</nav>', replacement_text, original_text)
```

You'll need to piece it all together, and make it work yourself, but I feel that's a solid approach to this problem.  HOWEVER, I re-iterate: I shudder at thinking someone will eventually update their website using this method.  Also, backup your files every time you run this, as it failing could results in unintended replacement/deletion of text.

Comment: Yeah Leon County schools are ridiculously lousy at what they call "security" They won't let you access the schools website from their own wifi because it could be a security vulnerability and if I showed you how hacked together the site is now this is far more better. The current website has a different look for every page and half the links are broken so even a hacked together page is still an improvement on what is currently implemented.

Though I do understand your criticizing in fact I have the tech department at my school contacting county to see if they can do something about php.

Comment: I just found out that they have asp and I already have a way to implement this but thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf This is intended to be a script that is run manually when the Navbar needs to change on what I assume to be a small number (under 1,000) of HTML files.  Furthermore, the pattern is a very simplistic one.  Using a simpler substitution method, like fnmatch "<nav id="mainNav">*</nav>" would be less versatile and break much easier (what if there's ever another </nav> on the page?). For this scenario, the extra seconds incurred via regex is completely acceptable.

Comment: @EiyrioüvonKauyf You're over-complicating this situation for no reason.  He's specifically stated in the question that they are static webpages that don't use Javascript, loads, or callbacks.  All he wants to do is replace one chunk of text with another.  Treat the HTML as text.  With the size of HTML files, and simplicity of this pattern, matches *will* only take a fraction of a second, and there is zero issue regarding scaling.

Comment: This is a lovely answer, thanks for your empathy and business understanding. I'm in a similar place and I'm not allowed to implement a solution using django/flask/php.

Answer (score 0):

Use a templating engine when creating your web pages / website: an example is `Jinja` you can use a [base html template](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/). You can do similar things in other engines as well

and there are many many options: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

if you're determined not to use an engine create a base.html and you're ok with this not being very extensible / readable / etc.

`stuff stuff $$$my_flag$$$ stuff stuff` and replace `$$$my_flag$$$` with a string replaceAll. Is that what you want?

Comment: I just want to replace a chunk of html and I am trying to avoid java script totally I figure this owuld be as easy as loading the file into memory looking for a certain like then replacing it with another file

Comment: My thing is I already have the entire webpage written I just need a way to update all the navbars I figured parsing a file then replacing a chunk would be easy enough maybe I was wrong. I have no access to the server this will be hosted and I don't believe it has any server side programming support.

Answer (score -1):

Does the server have SSI or PHP? There is an include function that does what you want. Look up SSI include

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/webmaster/article.php/3473341/SSI-The-Include-Command.htm

So you would just change the navbar file and it would change on all your pages that include it

Comment: No unfortunately I don't believe it does I am doing this for my school and I am a student not only do they not have server side scripting I believe I may be wrong. But they wouldn't let me know or access the server to test the page for "security reasons so I am trying to make is static.